# snapping 2 vector points Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs4, flash-cs3, cs4

I am trying to snap 2 vector points together but for some reason its moving the entire object instead of the point. I am trying to follow instructions in a book and the book shows that it is using the solid (filled) selection tool and it has the magnet turned on for snap options. It shows I am suppose to click where the (right triangle) appears beside the mouse arrow and then snap. but it keeps moving the entire Object even with the (right triangle) appear beside the mouse arrow. what could I be doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I correctly understood your question, but the filled selection tool (shortcut: V) is for moving the whole object ; you'll have to use the "unfilled" one (shortcut: A) to move points.

Comment: see, that is what I thought, but the book shows him using the filled selection arrow. So I was a little confused. He was connectiong 2 points and it showed a circle where they were connecting. I am pretty much trying to do that. I am trying to snap them together and its not working with the unfilled arrow

Answer (score 0):

the right angle symbol does indeed only select the vertex, not the whole object, as long as the object is at first *not selected at all*, then click and drag (without clicking to select first) you will then get a circle around the point and larger and darker circle at snap points